# handling void type in template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a templated function that invokes another function and stores its return value, then does some work before returning the value.  I'd like to extend this to handle `T = void`, and was wondering if specialization is my only option.

```
template<typename T>
T Foo( T(*Func)() ) 
{
    // do something first (e.g. some setup)
    T result = Func();
    // do something after (e.g. some tear down)
    return result;
}

// Is this specialization the only option?
template<>
void Foo<void>( void(*Func)() ) 
{
    // do something first (e.g. some setup)
    Func();
    // do something after (e.g. some tear down)
    return;
}

void Bar() {}
int BarInt() { return 1; }

int main()
{
    Foo<int>(&BarInt);
    Foo<void>(&Bar);
}
```

Or can the regular version of `Foo` be modified to handle the `void` type and basically do nothing in that case?  I was thinking that maybe my local result could be wrapped in a type that could handle `void` maybe, but could also see the assignment as being a deal-breaker.

Comment: Is _do something_ related to the `result` you just got?

Comment: No.  There's actually pre and post code to Func() that's important.  I'll add that.

Comment: Post what you're doing with the `result` please.

Comment: I'm not doing anything with the `result`, its just something that `Func()` returns that I'm kindly returning out.  The key to this function is that `Func()` is called in the middle of some other operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that your operation does not depend on the result of the function, you can do it without a specialization. It is ok for a function returning `void` to return an expression of type `void`. So the `return` part is not the troublesome one, but you need to figure out a way to do the pre and post operations. Constructors and destructors will help you there:

```
struct do_something_helper
{
    do_something_helper()
    {
        // do something first (e.g. take a lock)
    }
    ~do_something_helper()
    {
        // do something after (e.g. release a lock)
    }
};
```

Then you can write your function like this:

```
template<typename T>
T Foo( T(*Func)() ) 
{
    do_something_helper _dummy_helper; // constructor called here

    return Func();
    // destructor called here
}
```

For a more general solution using lambdas as you commented, it could look like this:

```
template< typename Pre, typename Post >
struct scope_guard
{
    scope_guard( Pre&& pre, Post&& post )
      : _post( std::forward< Post >( post ) )
    {
        pre();
    }
    ~scope_guard()
    {
        _post();
    }

    Post _post;
};

template< typename Pre, typename Post >
scope_guard< Pre, Post > make_scope_guard( Pre&& pre, Post&& post )
{
    return scope_guard< Pre, Post >( std::forward< Pre >( pre ), std::forward< Post >( post ) );
}

template<typename T>
T Foo( T(*Func)() ) 
{
    auto do_something_helper =
        make_scope_guard(
            [](){ /* do something first (e.g. take a lock) */ },
            [](){ /* do something after (e.g. release a lock) */ }
        );

    return Func();
}
```

A *type-erased* version using `std::function< void() >` would be easier to write and use, but it would be rather inefficient.

Comment: With lambdas and some existing code that invokes lamdas on destruction, this could work nicely.

Comment: I can handle that, but it would make for a better answer :-)

Comment: @JaredC: Note that the curious requirements for `operator->` overloads would be a good approach for _pre/post_ code execution as well.

Comment: @Kballo: care to elaborate?

Comment: @Eric: An overloaded `operator->` has to return an object to which `operator->` can be applied again, as many times as needed, until a pointer is returned for which `operator->` does `(*p).`

Comment: @K-ballo I got chained `operator->` calls working, but I can't quite tie it into the `Func()` and its return value, suggestions?

Comment: @JaredC: You would end up doing `something->call()` which would call `Func()`. One of those chained `operator->` calls should return a _guard_ class that handles _pre/post_ execution.

Comment: You should be careful with this approach that your `post` operations don't throw exceptions, as they're called in a destructor.

Answer (score 2):

No, you need the specialization since you cannot store void (as in `T result = Func();`).

If you're never gonna use the value, and you are fine with calling Func as the last thing, then you can actually:

```
return Func( );
```

both if func returns void or a type since the following is legal:

```
void f();
void g() {
    return f();
}
```

But if you need to temporarily store the return value, you need the specialization.

However, if you're gonna create a lot of these helper functions (Foo), and you don't want to have to specialize the particular Foo's for void each time, you can create a wrapper caller, which will perform the call, and when you want, return the value, be it void or some real type:

```
template< typename R >
class call_wrapper {
public:
    call_wrapper( std::function< R( void ) > f )
    : temp( std::move( f( ) ) )
    { }

    R&& return_and_destroy( ) {
        return std::move( temp );
    }

private:
    R temp;
};

template< >
class call_wrapper< void > {
public:
    call_wrapper( std::function< void(void) > f ) { f( ); }

    void return_and_destroy( ) { }
};
```

You can then do the following in all your Foo's you're gonna write, **without specialization**, since it's been taken care of once and for all in the wrapper above:

```
template<typename T>
T Foo( T(*Func)() ) 
{
    // do something first (e.g. some setup)
    call_wrapper< T > cw( Func );
    // do something after (e.g. some tear down)
    return cw.return_and_destroy( );
}
```

Comment: Using `std::function< void() >` results in _type-erasure_ which cannot be _inlined_, resulting in a rather inefficient `call_wrapper`.

Comment: Well then replace it with straight function pointers. The point of the example is to show what can be done with as little change to his existing code as possible.

Comment: But you still have a specialization for `void`, which the OP was trying to avoid...

Comment: sigh... I'm giving an example. It might help him. He might want to write lots of Foo's. With my example, they will not, **themselves**, need to be specialized. In my example, his Foo is left as is, in that the code runs as it's declared sequentially line by line down. You're solution works very nicely too, but it makes the code harder to follow. That might not be helping OP in the end.

Answer (score 2):

If all you're doing is taking and releasing a lock then you should use RAII instead of calling lock/unlock functions. This is especially true if `Func` could throw, as if it does the code after it will not be called.

Once you have an RAII lock (or some time of RAII object if you need more than locks), you can simply do this which works for `void`:

```
template<typename T>
T Foo( T(*Func)() ) 
{
    lock my_lock;
    return Func();
}
```

---

```
template<typename T>
T Foo( T(*Func)() ) 
{
    struct raii_wrapper {
      raii_wrapper(T(*Func)()) : Func(Func) {
        // pre effects
      }
      ~raii_wrapper() {
        // post effects
      }
      T(*Func)();
    } actions(Func);
    return Func;
}
```

Comment: There is other pre- and post- code that happen other than grabbing the lock, but +1 for the RAII suggestion.  I have to think if that will work.

Comment: @JaredC Updated with a different example.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain this is valid, but:

```
template<>
void Foo<T>( T(*Func)() ) 
{
    // do something first (e.g. some setup)
    return tearDown(Func());
}

template<>
T tearDown<T>( T result) 
{
    // do something after
    return result;
}
```